# Run Time ERROR, Missing module error in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

the code run fines when without passing variable

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 2)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""C:\Users\abc\Downloads\data.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table001 = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table001,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5""" & _
        ", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table002 (Page 3)", Formula:= _
```

if i pass a variable it shows module error

```
Dim var As String
 
var = Range("A1").Value

  ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 2)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""var""), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table001 = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table001,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5""" & _
        ", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table002 (Page 3)", Formula:= _
```

Comment: Is this code in a sub or function?

Comment: ` ... & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""" & var & """), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & ...`   you're passing the literal string "var" not the value of the variable with that name.

Comment: the var hold the value of cell i.e path that user will provide

Comment: i just wanted that user will pass the path of the pdf using cell a1 and cell a1 holds the path which i passes in Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""C:\Users\abc\Downloads\data.pdf"")

var = C:\Users\abc\Downloads\data.pdf

Comment: The previous comment was pointing out that you aren't using `var` as a variable. When you put it in quotes, it is just text - the letters v-a-r, not a variable at at all. Your reported error is quite strange (I can't remember seeing it very often) - where is this code? In  sheet module? In a standard module? Is it in a sub or function?

Comment: I have posted a macro which i was working on

Answer (score 0):

sub export()

Dim var As String

var = Range("A1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 2)", Formula:= _
"let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(var), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table001 = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table001,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5""" & _
", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table001 (Page 2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
.CommandType = xlCmdSql
.CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table001 (Page 2)]")
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.PreserveColumnInfo = True
.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table001__Page_2"
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

```
End With
```

End sub

var = Range("A1").Value will get the pdf filepath from CELL A1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't fixed the use of your variable. This is wrong (fourth line, with `var` in it):

```
var = Range("A1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 2)", _
Formula:= "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _ 
" Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(var), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & _
```

this might work (but doesn't really match your error description, so it's probably only part of the problem):

```
var = Range("A1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 2)", _
Formula:= "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _ 
" Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(" & var & "), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & _
```

I would really recommend you to back up, start with a simple test procedure that does almost nothing, and add to it bit by bit, little by little, checking as you go. There is a lot going on here and it is very hard to say where exactly the problem might lie.